# XSLt.transform gives me "ď»ż"

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, csv

I have XML:

```
<results>
    <Countries country="Albania">
        <Regions region="Centralna Albania">
            <Provinces province="Durres i okolice">
                <Cities city="Durres"
                            cityCode="2B66E0ACFAEF78734E3AF1194BFA6F8DEC4C5760">
                    <IndividualFlagsWithForObjects Status="1" />
                    <IndividualFlagsWithForObjects  Status="0" />
                    <IndividualFlagsWithForObjects status="2" />
                 </Cities>
             </Provinces>
        </Regions>
    </Countries>
    <Countries ....
```

Which is result of this part of query:

```
SELECT Countries.FileSystemName as country,
       Regions.DefaultName as region ,
       Provinces.DefaultName as province,
       cities.defaultname as city,
       cities.code as cityCode, 
       IndividualFlagsWithForObjects.value as Status
```

I have xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="string(',')" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="string('&quot;')" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="string('&#xD;')" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="results/countries" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="countries">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove normalize-space() if you want keep white-space at it is -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(.), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And is part of code

```
XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

doc.LoadXml("<results></results>");
XmlNode newNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);

while (newNode != null)
{
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
    newNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);
}                    

doc.Save(@"c:\listOfCities.xml");

XslCompiledTransform XSLT = new XslCompiledTransform();    
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();    


XSLT.Load(@"c:\xsltfile1.xslt", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

XSLT.Transform(doc.OuterXml,@"c:\myCities.csv");
```

Why now I have in my csv only one cell with value : ď»ż

Comment: What kind of output were you expecting to get?

Comment: Odd. What does the actual XML declaration at the top of your XML file look like? What editor are you using, and is your XML document definitely encoded in the character encoding as declared?

Just wondering if something odd is going on where you're not seeing non-standard characters in the document, bearing in mind the Albanian words will have diacritics (like umlauts) in them...

Comment: The `Transform` method in `XslCompiledTransform` takes an `XmlReader`, `IXPathNavigable`, or a string containing a URI to an xml document. Should the last line be `XSLT.Transform(@"c:\listOfCities.xml", @"c:\myCities.csv")`?

Answer (score 2):

The input xml (or xslt) probably starts with Unicode's Byte Order Mark, and is badly parsed by c# (for no obvious reason I can find..).

Open it in some hexeditor, look at first 3 bytes, and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

XML elements are named `Countries` and XSLT uses `countries` instead.

I'd also make processing of elements and attributes explicit:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/> 

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="string(',')" /> 
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="string('&quot;')" /> 
  <xsl:param name="break" select="string('&#xD;')" /> 

  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="results/Countries" /> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="Countries"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/> 
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" /> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="*"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> 
    <xsl:if test="*|following-sibling::*"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" /> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="@*"> 
    <!-- remove normalize-space() if you want keep white-space at it is --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(.), $quote)" /> 
    <xsl:if test="position() != last ()"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" /> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: unortunately this doesn't help

Comment: Maybe, a modified stylesheet will help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong character set. This a great link you should really read:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Like the title says, it's "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)".

Answer (score 1):

Your output encoding is set to encoding="iso-8859-1", but this [ISO code page](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859) does not contain the characters you mention. For example, ď is only defined in iso-8859-2.

My guess is therefore, that the problem is caused by a mismatch of encodings. Have a look at the generated file in a hex editor.

I am not sure whether the [XslCompiledTransform.Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method uses the encoding given in the XSLT to write the file.

Use the Transform() method which writes to an [XmlWriter based on a StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66dybzaw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and save the resulting string to a file controlling its encoding.

Answer (score 1):

ď»ż is what UTF8 files seem to start with for non UTF8 aware apps. Your Xml writer is outputting unicode, but the result wants to be ISO-8859-1 (as per  `<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>`

when calling 
XSLT.Transform(...) in your code, use the overload `Transform(String, XmlWriter)`
and create that XmlWriter with ISO-8859-1 encoding:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("c:\myCities.csv",settings);
```

and then use it for the transform

```
XSLT.Transform(doc.OuterXml,writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what that stylesheet is supposed to do. `EnableScript = true` makes no sense either. Try this:

```
string folderPath = @"path\to\your\folder";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(folderPath, "listOfCities.xml")))
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(folderPath, "myCities.csv")))
{
    var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(Path.Combine(folderPath, "citiesCsv.xslt"));
    xslt.Transform(reader, null, writer);
}
```

Where citiesCsv.xslt is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Countries">
      <xsl:value-of
        select="@country"/>,<xsl:value-of
        select="Regions/@region"/>,<xsl:value-of
        select="Regions/Provinces/@province"/>,<xsl:value-of
        select="Regions/Provinces/Cities/@city"/>
      <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant to do. I do recommend that you look into Dour High Arch's xslt suggestion. It would make things a bit cleaner.

C# code

```
XslCompiledTransform style = new XslCompiledTransform();
style.Load(@"c:\xsltfile1.xslt");
style.Transform(@"c:\listOfCities.xml", @"c:\myCities.csv");
```

xsltfile1.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="string(',')" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="string('&quot;')" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="string('&#xD;')" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="results/Countries" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Countries">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//@*" />
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(.), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

listOfCities.csv:

```
"Albania","Centralna Albania","Durres i okolice","Durres","2B66E0ACFAEF78734E3AF1194BFA6F8DEC4C5760","1","0","2"
```